# gwt i18n LocalizableResource file path

Tags: gwt, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to set resource properties files to localize my application.

```
public static interface MenuConstants extends Constants {

    String categoryCells();

}
```

And i have the corresponding `LocalizableResource_en.properties` :

```
categoryCells = Cell Widgets
```

But it fails in this line:

```
MenuConstants constants = GWT.create(MenuConstants.class);
```

With the message:

```
[TRACE] [XX] - Generating method body for categoryCells()
    [ERROR] [XX] - No resource found for key 'categoryCells '
    [WARN] [XX] - Searched the following resources:
```

I would like to know where i should put the `*.properties` files to get GWT to find the resource?

My `gwt.xml` file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/> 
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales"/>

<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr"/>
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n?hl=en#Bonjour), if you want your constants to be accessible in UiBinder templates as well as in Java code you have to name your files `LocalizableResource_<locale>.properties` and put them in the package `com.google.gwt.i18n.client`. Works for me.